# How to select ranges in a range of record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, gaps-and-islands

If I have a table like this

```
Number Status
------ ------
1      A
2      A
3      A
4      U
5      U
6      A
7      U
8      U
9      A
10     A
```

What query can I use to group the range into ranges where Status = A?

```
Range  Count  Status
-----  -----  ------
1-3    3      A
6-6    1      A
9-10   2      A
```

My query is

```
select min(number) || '--' || max(number), count(*), Status
from table
where Status = 'A'
group by Status

Range  Count  Status
-----  -----  ------
1-10   6      A
```

Comment: Can you show us the wanted result?

Comment: Hi Sir, please see block 2 for the expected result 
Range  Count  Status
-----       -----     ------
1-3        3         A
6-6        1         A
9-10      2         A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice way, fancy name "[Tabibitosan method](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1007478)" given by Aketi Jyuuzou.

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT num - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY num) grp,
  3      status,
  4      num
  5    FROM t
  6    )
  7  SELECT MIN(num)
  8    ||' - '
  9    || MAX(num) range,
 10    COUNT(*) cnt
 11  FROM data
 12  WHERE status='A'
 13  GROUP BY grp
 14  ORDER BY grp
 15  /

RANGE         CNT
------ ----------
1 - 3           3
6 - 6           1
9 - 10          2

SQL>
```

**Note** It is better to use `DENSE_RANK` to avoid duplicates.

**Table**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY num;

       NUM S
---------- -
         1 A
         1 A
         2 A
         2 A
         3 A
         4 U
         5 U
         6 A
         7 U
         8 U
         9 A

       NUM S
---------- -
        10 A

12 rows selected.
```

There are duplicates for num = 1.

Using **DENSE_RANK**:

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT num - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY num) grp,
  3      status,
  4      num
  5    FROM t
  6    )
  7  SELECT MIN(num)
  8    ||' - '
  9    || MAX(num) range,
 10    COUNT(*) cnt
 11  FROM data
 12  WHERE status='A'
 13  GROUP BY grp
 14  ORDER BY grp
 15  /

RANGE         CNT
------ ----------
1 - 3           5
6 - 6           1
9 - 10          2

SQL>
```

Using **ROW_NUMBER**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY num) grp,
  3      status,
  4      num
  5    FROM t
  6    )
  7  SELECT MIN(num)
  8    ||' - '
  9    || MAX(num) range,
 10    COUNT(*) cnt
 11  FROM data
 12  WHERE status='A'
 13  GROUP BY grp
 14  ORDER BY grp
 15  /

RANGE         CNT
------ ----------
2 - 3           2
1 - 2           2
1 - 6           2
9 - 10          2

SQL>
```

So, in case of duplicates, the **ROW_NUMBER** query would give incorrect results. You should use **DENSE_RANK**.

Comment: As checked using DENSE_RANK, I got less execution time. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b578/14)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table x(
  num_ number,
  status_ varchar2(1)
  );

insert into x values(1,'A');
insert into x values(2,'A');
insert into x values(3,'A');
insert into x values(4,'U');
insert into x values(5,'U');
insert into x values(6,'A');
insert into x values(7,'U');
insert into x values(8,'U');
insert into x values(9,'A');
insert into x values(10,'A');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select min(num_) || '-'  || max(num_) range_, status_,
count(1) count_
from
(
  select num_, status_,
  num_ - row_number() over (order by status_, num_) y --gives a group number to each groups, which have same status over consecutive records.
  from x
 )
 where status_ = 'A'
 group by y, status_
 order by range_
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b578/14/0)**:

```
| RANGE_ | STATUS_ | COUNT_ |
|--------|---------|--------|
|    1-3 |       A |      3 |
|    6-6 |       A |      1 |
|   9-10 |       A |      2 |
```